# Basic If statement not executing as expected in Sinatra "get" method

Tags: ruby, if-statement, sinatra

In my .erb file, I have the following jQuery call:

```
$.get(url, { point: pointValue, chore: investigate });
```

Both `point` and `chore` are integers.

In my .rb file, I have the following statement:

```
get '/estimate/:id' do

  print params[:chore]  # for debugging

  if params[:chore] == 1
    print "true!"
  end

end
```

When I print `params[:chore]`, the correct value is printed out in my console, either 0 or 1.

However, even in the cases when it is `1`, the `if` block does not execute, i.e. `"true!"` is not printed to the console.

I am completely stumped and confused! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the number `1` belongs to the `Fixnum` class. your `chore` value does probably not. convert it to an integer before comparing (`if params[:chore].to_i == 1`) or inspect the `chore` params key (`puts params[:chore].class`).

Comment: works perfectly! follow-up question: originally i had it as a boolean (true or false) but changed it an int (1 or 0) as i was debugging. is there a to_bool or something of that nature?

Comment: no, but you should be able to easily create your own `to_bool` method. you should probably open a new qustion.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters from a request always come back as type String. You need to convert that to an integer (via [String#to_i](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i)) in order for your comparison to work (or, compare with "1" instead).